# Python logging is splitting string into two lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, logging

I set up logging like so:

```
import logging

log_filename = 'foo'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING,
                format='%(asctime)s  ==  %(levelname)-8s  ==  %(message)s',
                datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                filename=log_filename,
                )
```

(FYI: I also defined a handler that writes CRITICAL messages or higher to the sys.stderr, but I'm pretty positive that is not causing my issue. If you think it is, let me know and I'll post that code as well.)

This setup worked well, for the most part. However, I ran into issues when I tried to log the following:

```
logging.critical("   DATE        TIME       BALANCE")
```

I expected the string to be logged as a single line. (Notably, my handler that writes to std.out expresses the string as a single line in the terminal.) Instead, this is the result in the log file:

```
06/04/2017 11:23:51 PM  ==  CRITICAL  ==     DATE
     TIME       BALANCE
```

It seems that the logger is splitting the string into different lines for some reason. The issue is not caused by the length of the string, because I have logged longer strings that show up as a single line. Thus, it seems to me that it must be related to the content of the above string (which includes a mixture of spaces and tabs between "DATE", "TIME", and "BALANCE"). Does anyone know what is causing this behavior?

** Edit #1: Out of an abundance of caution, I added "import logging" to make clear the module that I am using. (I also fixed some typos.)

** Edit #2: After doing some experimenting at TessellatingHeckler's request, I am embarrassed to say that the issue was not the contents of the string at all. I feel silly for thinking that was the issue. It seems that the following lines of code actually caused the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('bar.csv')
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    logging.critical(str("  " + row['Date']) + "        " + str(row['Time']) + "    " + str(row['Balance']))
```

I used the above code to log the contents of a csv file. Similar to first log I posted above, the above code results in the string being split into two lines, like so:

```
06/05/2017 12:23:45 AM  ==  CRITICAL  ==    6/3/17
        20:14:19    789.35
```

Oddly, after this occurs and it part of the log file, then even if I remove the problematic csv-writing part of the code and run only the following:

```
logging.critical("   DATE        TIME       BALANCE")
```

I still get:

```
06/04/2017 11:23:51 PM  ==  CRITICAL  ==     DATE
     TIME       BALANCE
```

in the log file. In contrast, if I run the same code except log to a new log file (without the problematic csv-writing code), I get a single line as I had originally expected/desired:

```
06/04/2017 11:23:51 PM  ==  CRITICAL  ==     DATE        TIME       BALANCE
```

Does anyone know what could be causing such strange behavior?

** Edit 3: I added "import pandas as pd" to make clear that I was using the pandas module.

Comment: Try .. deleting characters one at a time until the effect stops, see which it was?

Comment: I am guessing that your CSV file contains values with newlines or other symbols you are logging.

Comment: But why would that affect my other logging entries? Oddly, if I run the same code (including the problematic csv-writing code) but have it log to .txt file rather than a .log file, the problem goes away...

Comment: Or the string you are concatenating before sending to `logging.critical` contains such symbols

Comment: In such cases, when it's reproducible, I use `ipdb`/`pdb`. First we need to ensure that the problem exists -- that it's not interpretation issue in your log viewer. Then we need to find a point in code which gives a variable containing the problematic string with newlines in it. Then put `print`s or `pdb.set_trace()` somewhere before that that code to track when the bad value is created.